# Sequelize js - limit and Sorting bug

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

What is the proper way to sort the query in sequelize js?

example:

```
db.model.findAll({ 
    where: conditions, 
    order: 'postDate DESC', 
    limit: 10, 
    offset: 0, 
    include: [model1, model2] 
}).complete(function(err, results){console.log(results); });
```

Resulting in pulling the results of the limit and offset, first and then it does the sorting. What should I do to do the sorting first before limiting the results?

---

in the future who will encounter this bug, this is the fix

```
order: [["postDate","DESC"]]
```

Comment: I came across exactly same issue today and order: [["postDate","DESC"]] fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: You should answer the question yourself and accept it

Answer (score 20):

You have to specify it like this: `order: [["postDate","DESC"]]`