# Sequelize Order within Query and Sub-Query

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out how I can use the `order` property to order both my sub-query and parent query. With current setup, the order clause orders the parent query, but not the sub-query. Is this possible? If so, how I can achieve it?

**Here is my full query:**

```
models.Blog.findAll({
            order: 'blog_date DESC',
            limit: 10,
            include: [
            {
                model: models.Topic,
                attributes: ['topicName'],
                required: false
            },
            {
                model: models.BlogComment,
                include: [{
                    model: models.User,
                    attributes: ['userId','firstName', 'lastName']
                }],
                required: false
            }]
        })
```

**Produces a query:**

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ... FROM blog LIMIT 10)
LEFT OUTER JOIN topic ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_comment ...
ORDER BY blog.blog_date DESC;
```

**I'm looking to include the following `ORDER BY`:**

```
FROM (SELECT ... FROM blog ORDER BY blog.blog_date LIMIT 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sorder subqueries the same way, add order attribute

```
models.Blog.findAll({
            order: 'blog_date DESC',
            limit: 10,
            include: [
            {
                model: models.Topic,
                attributes: ['topicName'],
                required: false
            },
            {
                model: models.BlogComment,
                include: [{
                    model: models.User,
                    attributes: ['userId','firstName', 'lastName'],
                    order : 'firstName DESC'
                }],
                required: false
            }]
        })
```

**Update**:

You will need to try

```
order: [["blog_date","DESC"]]
```

rather than

```
order: 'blog_date DESC'
```

Kindly refer to the following link

[Sequelize js - limit and Sorting bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534339/sequelize-js-limit-and-sorting-bug)

Comment: Keval Gohil thank you for your answer, but the subquery in this statement is actually the blog table itself and the attribute that I want to order is the same in the parent query and sub-query, `blog_date`. Updated my question to reflect what I mean.

Comment: there is a bug in sequelize i will update the link to work around awnser

Comment: Thank you pointing out the bug discussion. I see what you are saying that `[["blog_date","DESC"]]` is the best way to achieve what I'm looking for, however it appears that when I use this method, the sub-query is ordering with the aliased version while the outer query uses the actual column name `blogDate` vs `blog_date` so I get an error with the order value above. Any ideas for what should be changed? Maybe this should be asked in a separate question?

Comment: Nevermind, if I use `sequelize.col('blogDate')` then I don't run into the issue. Thank you so much for your help!